# How to fix Outlook rendering links as plain text

Tags: html, email, outlook, hyperlink, html-email

Any link that does not have "http" or "https" is renders as plain text. How can I fix this without adding https to all the links?

Following is an example of the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just what Outlook.com does. There is no way around it other than to ensure URLs are properly configured with the http or https protocol. There is no reason to not include it. Not having a protocol is in fact wrong, so that's what Outlook.com is complaining (correctly) about.